# Continuous function with logarithm

Tags: limits, continuity

$\frac{log (1+\frac{x}{p})- log(1-\frac{x}{q})}{x}$ $,x\neq 0$
The function is continuous at $x=0$ , and we need to find $f(0)$.

The numerator goes to $0$ $(log1 - log 1)$
And the denominator goes to $0$ as well.
So $f(0)= 0/0=1$
Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: compute $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{log (1+\frac{x}{p})- log(1-\frac{x}{q})}{x}$ with l'Hospital

Comment: Oh! I got it, the answer is $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}$?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use equivalents.

Since, for small values of $\epsilon$, $\log(1+\epsilon)\sim \epsilon$, then $$\log (1+\frac{x}{p})\sim \frac{x}{p}$$ $$\log (1-\frac{x}{q})\sim -\frac{x}{q}$$ $$\log (1+\frac{x}{p})-\log (1-\frac{x}{q})\sim \frac{x}{p}+\frac{x}{q}=x\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} \right)$$